# msdeploy how to grant read/write permission for IIS_IUSRS to c:\windows\temp folder

Tags: msdeploy

I am adding this item in the ItemGroup in the project wpp.targets file.

```
<MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
    <Path>%windir%\TEMP</Path>
    <setAclUser>IIS_IUSRS</setAclUser>
    <setAclAccess>Read,Write,Modify</setAclAccess>
    <setAclResourceType>Directory</setAclResourceType>
    <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclUser;setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
</MsDeploySourceManifest>
```

and this on the parameter section

```
<MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="TempFolderPermissionSetAclParam">
    <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
    <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
    <Description>Add read, write permission for IIS_IUSRS to the temp folder.</Description>
    <DefaultValue>%windir%\TEMP</DefaultValue>
    <Value>%windir%\TEMP</Value>
    <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
    <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
    <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
  </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
```

it generate this line in the manifest xml file

but there is an error message says:
Error: A value for the 'setAclUser' setting must be specified when the 'setAcl'
provider is used with a physical path.

what's missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you asked this, but on the surface this looks more or less correct: the key point for specifying an absolute path are that you include setAclUser in the AdditionalProviderSettings, as well as an element for setAclUser.

Ultimately, while your SourceManifest file might appear correct when you build the package, what seems to matter though is the setAclUser settings on the setAcl elements within the archive.xml file contained within the zip that is created. Open that up and ensure that the value you expect for setAclUser is present.

As well, Visual Studio makes liberal use of caching where MSBuild files are concerned; practically speaking it seems that Visual Studio will respect changes made only to pubxml files and project files such as csproj. When making changes to any other target files, you should close Visual Studio and reopen after making each edit. This could explain why your seemingly-correct solution wasn't working: it might have simply been stale target file caches.